# retrieving facebook event comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, restfb, facebook-events

I am using RestFB to retrieve/fetch the posts and comments from my facebook page; however the request does not return an event post as I would expect and then further comments (from friends etc.) on the event post

On my facebook page:

I create an Event on my facebook page.
I see the Event post on my facebook page that references the new Event. 
My application (via RestFB) can retrieve the Event post.
However, facebook does not return any of the comments on the Event post on my page.

Note: I can use the Event /feed to get the comments on the Event, but this does not include any comments on the original page Event post.

The facebook id's given to the Event post (and comments) do not appear to have any reference to the Page Id or Event Id - so I if I can retrieve the comments via some other means?

Has anyone else encountered this issue - is there a solution? workaround?

Is this a limitation of the facebook graphAPI?

Comment: Same problem here and I think facebook has their limitation.